# Magento session loss at 3D secure redirect

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, opayo

I'm using Magento 1.9.3.8 with the Ebizmarts SagePay extension (direct integration) running on an Ubuntu 16.04 server (apache2, php 7.1), and have encountered with the situation when the customer loses their session when redirecting from the 3D secure form to `Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_DirectPaymentController::callback3dAction`:

```
Mage_Core_Exception: Please select a valid payment method. in /var/www/html/mage/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/mage/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(315): Mage::throwException('Please select a...')
#1 /var/www/html/mage/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(222): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->_validate()
#2 /var/www/html/mage/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(238): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitNominalItems()
#3 /var/www/html/mage/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(815): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#4 /var/www/html/mage/app/code/local/Ebizmarts/SagePaySuite/Model/SagePayDirectPro.php(280): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#5 /var/www/html/mage/app/code/local/Ebizmarts/SagePaySuite/Model/SagePayDirectPro.php(1092): Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Model_SagePayDirectPro->directCallBack3D(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Payment), 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx')
#6 /var/www/html/mage/app/code/local/Ebizmarts/SagePaySuite/controllers/DirectPaymentController.php(194): Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Model_SagePayDirectPro->saveOrderAfter3dSecure('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx')
#7 /var/www/html/mage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_DirectPaymentController->callback3dAction()
#8 /var/www/html/mage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('callback3d')
#9 /var/www/html/mage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 /var/www/html/mage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 /var/www/html/mage/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /var/www/html/mage/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}
```

The sessions are saved in the file system. The session TTL is 1 day. I've checked the access log, compared it with the session files and found 3 files which were created when redirecting the customer from the 3D form. A new session causing the creation of a new quote with no payment method assigned which leads to the exception from above, as the quote can't be validated.

The customer's user agent is Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36.

Is it something to do with the customer's device or my server?

Comment: It's hard to say what could be going on. I've seen similar issues caused by Magento session validations. If it's enabled, that could very well be the issue here: https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/system-operations/session-validation.html

Comment: @MladenIlić all of them are disabled